# Replace all non alpha-numeric characters with dots using bash commands

Tags: regex, bash

How can I replace all non alpha-numeric characters with dots using bash commands?

- Sequences of non alpha-numeric characters should be replaced with a single dot.

E.g. input string:

```
test/my-1st$@#@-t_-/ \_est
```

expected output string:

```
test.my.1st.t.est
```

Attempt to do this with `tr` resulted in a string with a trailing `.`:

```
echo "test/my-1st$@#@-t_-/ \_est" | tr -sc [:alnum:] .
```

(Online test: https://rextester.com/XPSVW41540)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
echo "test/my-1st$@#@-t_-/ \_est" | sed -e "s/\W/./g" | sed -e "s/_/./g" | tr -s .
```

1. Replace non word characters (non `a-zA-Z_`) with dot (`.`)
2. Replace underscores (`_`) with dot (`.`)
3. Squash sequences of dots into a single dot

Online test: https://rextester.com/GJOW76941

A shorter option:

```
echo "test/my-1st$@#@-t_-/ \_est" | sed -e "s/\W/_/g" | tr -s _ .
```

1. Replace non word characters (non `a-zA-Z_`) with underscore (`_`)
2. Squash and replace underscores (`_`) with dot (`.`)

Comment: for `tr -s . .`, `tr -s .` suffices. You just need the second parameter if you want to squeeze and convert into another value

Answer (score 1):

Using Bash's variable substitution and extglobbing:

```
$ foo='test/my-1st$@#@-t_-/ \_est' echo ${foo//+([^[:alnum:]])/.}
test.my.1st.t.est
```

Update - example:

```
shopt -s extglob
foo='test/my-1st$@#@-t_-/ \_est'
foo2=${foo//+([^[:alnum:]])/.}
echo $foo2
```

Comment: What version does this require? - Test fails: https://rextester.com/DFFD9365

Comment: It uses extglob (`+(...)`), you should `shopt -s extglob` first. Apparently it works in Rextester, too.